# Does STL sort support UTF8?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, utf-8

Does the STL sort function support alphabetical sorting of names which have UTF-8 characters in them? Say names from German/French language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting UTF-8 strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611302/sorting-utf-8-strings)

Answer (score 8):

That entirely depends on how you store the UTF-8 characters and how your comparer looks like. The `sort` function is completely agnostic of the elements it sorts.

But you probably mean “… when stored in a `char` array” and then the answer is **no** since the `char`s will store individual bytes of a given UTF-8 character, instead of the logical character. The `sort` function sorts *elements* delimited by iterators. `sort` works only if the iterators / the elements they refer to are aware of the data that they contain. This isn’t the case for an array of `char`s that encode UTF-8.

The “correct” solution here is to parse the UTF-8 input into an array of proper (normalised) Unicode code points, sort those, and translate back to UTF-8.

Comment: I may actually have misread your question so it’s possible that other answers apply. Also have a look in the “possibly related” question mentioned in the comments below your question.

Comment: It sounds like the string class, not the sorting algorithm, is the real problem. Get your data right. Algorithms come afterwards. `std::string` is `char*`-based, as Konrad says. wstring and QString etc are better-suited for this task.

Answer (score 2):

All that is required is the proper comparison function. You can probably find one in [ICU - International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) . Look specifically at [Collation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation).

Comment: This is insufficient since UTF-8 characters may span more than one byte and `sort` will not be aware of this, and consider each `char` (= byte) in the input as a separate item.

Comment: @Konrad, I don't understand your comment - `sort` doesn't attempt to interpret the data it's sorting, it leaves that job to the comparison function. You said so yourself in your own answer: "The sort function is completely agnostic of the elements it sorts."

Comment: I may have misread the question, thinking that OP wanted to sort individual *characters* in a string.

Answer (score 1):

c++0x [supports UTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#New_string_literals)

This has nothing to do with STL.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++0x support for UTF literals doesn’t help at all in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you refer to the Standard Template Library - and the answer is no.

None of the standard libraries has a text string type. There are `char` arrays, - but that's just a vector of bytes. There is `std::string` but that's a string of bytes (or 16bit words, or anything like that) basically. It has no notion of characters, let alone encodings.